# Center image in Steam page

Tags: steam

I am struggling to Center my image in my game's Steam page.

`[img][center]` --> Error

`[center][img]` --> Just prints a text "center" before and after the image :(.

How would a mere mortal center the image on Steam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to do with Steam's markdown. I just opted to make my image exactly 618px wide (unsure if this has some special relevance, I would suggest experimenting with larger images too and see if those are automatically fit [most likely they will]).
So center your wanted content on a larger transparent image.

Comment: That makes me so sad, but well, we will live with what we have right ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but for future reference this is doable by inserting `&nbsp;` characters in the description text. If you do it immediately before the `[img]` tag it will push the image slightly to the right. My images are 400px wide and I needed 26 of those non-breaking spaces to get the image to center.

Note that if you open the description editor again, the non-breaking spaces will be replaced by normal spaces, and if you save that, the centering will not work! So make sure you edit your description in a separate file that you copy-paste into the description box.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Its about as sad as the accepted answer.

Comment: Haha yeah sometimes you really notice how old the Steam codebase is...